# Conditional object class template tagging Django

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to replicate HTML cards based on a uniform model:

**Models.py**

```
class Uniform(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=11)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length = 6)
    size = models.CharField(choices=CLOTHES_SIZE, max_length=4)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uniforms/')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['category']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {} - {} - ${}'.format(self.category, self.description, self.size, self.price)
```

**Views.py**

```
def item_list(request):
    uniform = Uniform.objects.all()
    description = Uniform.objects.order_by().values('description').distinct()
    category = Uniform.objects.order_by().values('category').distinct()
    context = {
    'uniform':uniform,
    'description': description,
    'category': category
    }
    return render(request, 'apparelapp/item_list.html', context)
```

**html**

```
<div class="row wow fadeIn">
    {% for item in description %}
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

      <div class="card">

        <div class="view overlay">
          <img src="" alt="">
          <a>
            <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
          </a>

        </div>

        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <label>
            <h5>{{ item.description }}</h5>
          </label>
           <h5>

             {% if uniform.description %}
            <strong>
              <label for="">{{ uniform.category }}</label>
            </strong>
          </h5>
            {% endif %}

          <!--<h4 class="font-weight-bold blue-text">
            <strong>${{item.price}}</strong>
            <div class="dropdown">
              {% for size in item.size %}
              <ul>
                {{size}}
              </ul>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </h4> -->
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

What I get is the item description, but not the item category: I am trying to say, if the uniform's description is shown, show the uniform's category - but it is blank
[image]

I have tried formatting to call on just the uniform category, but then I 4x as many cards (EX: a card for apron small to apron xlarge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use wrong variable to access `uniform`'s category.

More easily is to iterate over your `Uniform` items. You may pass all its items to context:

**Views.py**

```
def item_list(request):
    uniform = Uniform.objects.all()
    context = {'uniform': uniform}
    return render(request, 'apparelapp/item_list.html', context)
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row wow fadeIn">
    {% for item in uniform %}
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="view overlay">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                    <a>
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <label>
                        <h5>{{ item.description }}</h5>
                    </label>
                    <h5>
                        {% if item.description %}
                        <strong>
                            <label for="">{{ item.category }}</label>
                        </strong>
                    </h5>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Also, I formated your **HTML** file a little bit.